# Equal proportional and derivative gains of PID

Tags: pid

Is it common to take equal values for the proportional and derivative gains of a PID controller? if so what does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mohammad, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, whenever someone asks about PID gains, my immediate reaction is to refer them to the [Ziegler-Nichols tuning method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method) as it's a pretty standard way to get good response from a PID controller.

As you can see from the table there, no, the proportional and derivative gains are not typically equal.

I don't know what you're asking when you say "what does it mean" for a gain to be a particular value, but remember that the gains act on reference *error*. If your reference value is a speed then the derivative gain acts on the derivative of the speed error, which means it acts on the acceleration difference between the reference and feedback signals.

If you're looking for more meaning for the gain values, I would refer you to [the original paper](http://staff.guilan.ac.ir/staff/users/chaibakhsh/fckeditor_repo/file/documents/Optimum%20Settings%20for%20Automatic%20Controllers%20(Ziegler%20and%20Nichols,%201942).pdf) (from the references section of the Wiki page) but, as you can see from the gain values, the integral and derivative gains depend on the period of the control oscillations, which means they depend on the properties of the plant. I don't believe there's a general statement you can make about the absolute values of any gain.